# Background color doesn't add

Tags: asp.net, html, css, background-color

I have a table as :

```
<div class="Bar" > 
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkHome" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Home"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td width="20%">
                                   </td>
                <td width="20%">
                                  </td>
                <td width="20%">
                                   </td>
                <td width="20%">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

i tried adding Background color through css on table as

```
.Bar table tr td
{
    background-color:Maroon;

    }
```

but doesn't give the background color.Thanks for assistance.

Comment: The td has no data, therefore no height so there's nothing to work with

Comment: It's perfectly working, there's no problem with the code. Just add some data to the <td> and you'll see the background color OR give some height to table.

Comment: Sir, i have added asp label with that. So i don't understand why it is not working with it?

Comment: i have updated the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**css**

```
 .Bar table tr td
        {
            background-color: Maroon;
            height:50px;
        }
```

**Html**

```
<div class="Bar">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">Hello
                </td>
                <td width="20%">Hello
                </td>
                <td width="20%">Hello
                </td>
                <td width="20%">Hello
                </td>
                <td width="20%">Hello
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried, it works

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/59rTL/)

```
<div class="Bar" > 
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td width="20%"></td>
            <td width="20%">aaa
                              </td>
            <td width="20%">
                               </td>
            <td width="20%">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>



.Bar table tr td
{
    background-color:Maroon;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works properly. i think your problem is from `<td></td>` tag, that is empty. see here http://jsfiddle.net/sYfLR/